# Troubles using jquery get to retrieve data from the server and place in a div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new to jquery and I am having problems trying to retrieve an item from the database and display the results. I am using codeigniter php.

What i am trying to do is this. I do a search, the search returns a list of posible results which is displayed in a div called venue_description. Onclick of one of the items from the list, I want it to replace the list with the item that is being clicked upon. but for some reason it does not work

In order to do that I did this:

In my model I pass the id of the item that is being clicked upon on the list through the onclick function

```
<--- this is in venue_model.php -->

$output .= '<li><a href="#self" class="menulink" class=&{ns4class}
         . ' onClick="changeDiv(\'' . $venue_details->VenueID . '\')">
```

The `venueID` is passed through the `changeDiv` which is in the `divUpdater.php` This is where the problem is. The `$.get` doesn't work. Can someone see the mistake? The Item retrieved is to be displayed in `venue_description` div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    base_url = '<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function changeDiv(venueID) {
        $.get(base_url + 'home/get_venue_description/' + venueID, function(data) {
            $('#venue_description').html(data);

        });
    }
</script>
```

`changeDiv(venueID)` calls the `get_venue_description(venueID)` in the `home.php` controller to retrieve the specific item from the database.

```
function get_venue_description($venueID){
    echo $this->venue_model->retrieveData($venueID);
}
```

Can anyone see the problem in this code? I have spent too much time try to find the mistake. Please help!

Comment: You need to format your question properly; right now your code is being interpreted as HTML. so we can't see it. Also, proofreading might make someone more likely to help. ;)

Comment: I've corrected your code formatting as best I can but please have a look here; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: What do you mean "The $.get doesnt work"? The browser doesn't even execute the GET?

Comment: It is as god as not writing a lines of code there. It is not calling the get_venue_description() method in the home controller and passing the venueID parameter. Can u see y? pls

Comment: and displaying  the results on the div .(venue_description)

Comment: Dave Anderson  the link u posted goes to a random page

Comment: Can you verify that the `base_url` is correct? Make sure that `base_url+'home/get_venue_description/'` resolves to the URL you're expecting. That'd be step 1.

Comment: Then make sure that the venueID is added correctly to the end of URL.

Comment: I think it is something to do with this  ---<a href="#self"---- when I click on one of the items on the list it shows this url. ---http://localhost/Counter/index.php#self  ------

Comment: how do I change it to give me the right url

Comment: Actually I dont need to change the url. All I want is the div --venue_descrption -- to be updated. Cant that be done without having the url being right. So everything in divUpdate.php should work in the background and return the result without having the url go home/get_venue_descritption/id=3 ...bla bla??

Answer (score 0):

Do you have firebug installed so you can check that the get is being fired?

maybe you can change this to echo debug string to test the problem is not in the model.

```
function get_venue_description($venueID){
    echo 'This is a test responce';
}
```